# AHK script to change RButton Behavior

Tags: autohotkey

I want to make a script that would allow me to click once every time I press the mouse, however, if instead of letting go immediately, I hold the RMB for more than 0.25s it would click again on release.

Essentially allowing me to use RMB normally as long as I don't hold it for too long but allowing me to do a double click if held.

This is a work around since my mouse's button gets stuck if I click too fast and I'm not able to get a new one atm.

The purpose of this is to be able to use my mouse on PS and to play the one game i play some times: Black Ops 2 while i save enough for a new mouse. In the context of the game, i want to be able to use Toggle ADS as a base and be able to use the toggle  by default by just clicking but be able also do a Hold to ADS with the same button on the fly without changing the game's configuration.

I am not very proficient at AHK and this is all I got so far, holding works fine, however if I don't hold, it does a double click which is annoying.

```
RButton Down::
Send {Click, Right}
       keywait RButton, t.25
     if errorlevel
       keywait RButton, 
    Send {RButton Up} 
return
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could maybe do some trickery with multiple `KeyWait`s, but I wouldn't recommend time consuming processing inside hotkey labels in any case due to AHKs single threaded nature.

Here's something very simple I'd recommend instead:

```
~*RButton::RClickTime := A_TickCount

~*RButton Up::
    if (A_TickCount - RClickTime >= 250)
        Click, Right
return
```

So first when we press down RButton (note that there is no "down" state for hotkey names, the key name itself means it being pressed down) we store the current system time with [`A_TickCount`](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Variables.htm#TickCount).
And we use the [`~`](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm#Tilde) modifier for the hotkey so the keypress itself isn't consumed.
And the [`*`](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm#wildcard) modifier is used so holding down e.g. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> or <kbd>Shift</kbd>, etc, wouldn't make the hotkey not work.

Then on RButton release (`RButton Up::`) we compare the current system time with the stored system time to see if over 250ms passed. If so, we send another right click with [`Click, Right`](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Click.htm) (don't use a [send command](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Send.htm) here, it isn't really intended for this).

Comment: OMG this works like a charm, thank you a LOT! 

How could i make it work with IfWinActive? 

Id like to make it so it only works in game and if I alt tab, for it to break any action. 

or maybe a key toggle would be nice, otherwise, thank you a lot!

Comment: Also, could it be done so pressing shift breaks the timer? because when I hold, if i press shift, it breaks ADS within the game, but if i let go afterwards, it will break sprinting to aim, it just got me killed lol

Comment: `ShiftkeyPressed := false

~*RButton::RClickTime := A_TickCount
    While (GetKeyState("RButton", "P"))
 {
  if (GetKeyState("LShift", "D"))
  {
   ShiftKeyPressed := true
   
   break
  }
 }

~*RButton Up::
    if(ShiftKeyPressed) {
  return
 } else { 
    if (A_TickCount - RClickTime >= 250)
        Click, Right
  ShiftkeyPressed := false
        return
    }
 
LShift::
 Send LShift
 While (GetKeyState("LShift", "P"))
 {
  if (GetKeyState("RButton", "D"))
  {   
   break
  }
 }`

It doesnt break the timer and spams types "Lshift" every time i press LShift key

Comment: Uhh, that code has a whole lot of problems ranging from unreachable code to syntax & logic errors. But for the WinActive check you'd use the [`#IfWinActive`](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/_IfWinActive.htm) directive, and for toggle on off you'd use [`Suspend`](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Suspend.htm) (e.g. `*F1::Suspend`) and not sure I understand your aiming thing. But "break timer on shift" sounds like you could just set the stored system time to e.g. zero on shift press, so the 250ms check will never pass `~*Shift::RClickTime := 0`.

Comment: Where should i add `~*Shift::RClickTime := 0`? adding it at the end doesnt seem to work, if i hold then press shift, it will still do the click after i let go.

As for explaining the aiming thing: The game will enter ADS (aim down the sights) mode if i Rclick once, but will leave if i Rclick again. The game has a sprinting function so if im in ADS mode and then press sprint (LShift) it will also leave ADS mode. 

I want to be able to also simulate HOLD to ADS mode (were pressing activates it and releasing deactivates it) without losing the functionality of the sprint taking me out of ADS

Comment: in short: My objective is to be able to keep using toggle ads as long as I click the button once without holding it BUT be able to hold it and not leave ADS mode until i let go. However, i also want to make it so shift cancels the second rclick when releasing because sprinting would have already taken me out of ADS mode.

Comment: Oh, don't make it zero on shift press, I was being silly, make it a really big number. Make it like `5000000000`, that should do it.

Comment: I tried setting a really high number but still double clicks, i mean if anything ,setting a really high number wouldnt do anything as anything higher than 250 means its gonna work exactly the same lol. 

is there a way to make it have an upper limit?

Comment: I tried adding an upper limit but doesnt seem to work, maybe lshift isnt compatible?
`~*RButton::RClickTime := A_TickCount
    

~*RButton Up::
    
    if (A_TickCount - RClickTime >= 250)
        Click, Right
  else  if (A_TickCount - RClickTime > 10000)
  {
  }
  
~*Shift::RClickTime := 5000000000

return`

Comment: Not the number in the condition, the number the Shift hotkey sets to the stored system time variable. `~*Shift::RClickTime := 5000000000`. This would make it so the condition for the second right click could never pass. It works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're missing some curly braces around your `if` block; but I think you can implement the right double-click functionality with something as simple as,

```
RButton::
  KeyWait RButton, T.25
  numberOfClicks := errorLevel + 1
  Send {Click Right %numberOfClicks%}
return
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for your fast response! While the functionality is the same, the problem that i had orginally remains, i thought of something just like that when i started trying but the delay throws me off. I need to control when the second click happens and also i need the first (and some times only) click to happen as soon as i press the button and then the second click exactly when i release the button. In reality, i dont need an actual double click as much as i need 2 controlled clicks. 

I've updated the OP to be more specific, its not just for work, its for a game as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
~RButton:: ;*When Right Mouse Button is Down, do the following.*
keywait RButton, T.25 ;*Wait (250 milliseconds) for it to be released.*
if errorlevel { ;*When it exceeds the said time*
keywait RButton ;*Wait for it to be released*
Send, {RButton Up} ;*Send Right Mouse Button up*
}
return
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, while this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.